# Product ID conflict for migrating Native Apps to flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, app-store, google-play-services

I already have an app on PlayStore and AppStore. But now I am making the whole app in Flutter. For in-app purchases and other similar tasks, I need to specify a single Product ID in both Google Play and App Store console. Since my existing app has 2 different product IDs 1 each IOS and Android, how should I solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use your old different id's. First use Android Id and generate apk for playstore then change the package name as your ios app store and generate ipa for that.